# Network Game by Adobe Air programming in Adobe Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, networking, multiplayer

I want to create a simple game (Adobe Air) based on 2 players using ActionScript 3.
Let's assume I want to create online chess game.
So that I can play with my friend at work, at home, from anywhere via internet.
Should I use flash server? Or something similar for this purpose, or there is simpler way to connect 2 players and make fully functional interaction between them?
I need to know, where to start.
Any online tutorials, sample codes will really help me.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Flash Media Server or notorious multiuser servers. Some random names for you to search: Union (formerly Unity), Electroserver, SmartFoxServer, Mesmotronic, RED5, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's possible to create a socket server using AIR2, so it would be possible to connect directly to another player. However, this requires that the host has an external IP, which is not the case in most work/home networks. It would be better to build a proper TCP/IP server (either using FMS or some other system - I would look at nodeJS or java).

Comment: And if you decide on Java, [this](http://www.broculos.net/en/article/how-make-multi-client-flash-java-server) article might be a good place to start.