# AS3 library for multiuser drawing application

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, networking, drawing, paint

There are several flashbased painting/sketching online apps that allow multiple users to paint simultaneously. Some examples:

```
flockdraw.com
scribblar.com
twiddla.com
```

For a project, we want to implement something similar. The question is, whether we need to start from scratch or whether there are any libraries available that could facilitate development (especially the networking part).

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think there can be any special libraries. What do you suppose that library should do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8654368/network-game-by-adobe-air-programming-in-adobe-flash/8656491#8656491

Answer (score 1):

For drawing in Flash I always use Graffiti http://www.nocircleno.com/graffiti/ as it has most drawing features that I need.

For a bunch of other game type of stuff, such as networking you can look into PlayerIO http://playerio.com/documentation/reference/actionscript3/

If you decide do do the networking manually I would definitely use sockets.